# VOIP and IM communication without a server

Tags: voip, p2p, instant-messaging, windows

Typical enterprise VOIP solutions like [MS Comm Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_Communications_Server) require a server computer to handle communications. Is there any program that can do it Peer-2-Peer (P2P) without a server, and directly call and chat with the target computer, directly on the network? (not using the Internet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to have a server you could use Microsoft Office Communication Server hosted. Then no server.(for you at least)

Most SIP IP pbx's allow video calls but then you will need a server...hmmm...pbxnsip is a IP PBX that can do video calls and it runs on a sheeva plug (tiny server $100)...

Without internet voip isn't very useful.

Answer (score 3):

Using a h323 client like ekiga you should be able call another client by ip address.

Answer (score 2):

1st, I don't use it but found it via google: [P2P VoIp 1.1](http://www.soft32.com/download_64506.html)

They say it'S freeware and within the download you will find the sourcecode.

Maybe it is intresting for you, we are using a ejabberd-server with the jinjgle (voip) extension in our company network. Since we managing the accounts by ourself we can allow external poeple to connect to this service.

Best regards

arl from germany

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is actually one call blink. 
Blink will "find" all the clients near it which is kind of cool

Answer (score 0):

My bad, 'missed the without internet'. ;)

You should look for sip clients that support Bonjour/Zeroconf/DNS-SD client discovery.
I don't use desktop SIP clients but googling turned up one that has many platforms under the supported list and appears to be open source.

[SIP Communicator](http://www.sip-communicator.org/index.php/Development/Roadmap)